# Countability of conjugacy classes in profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

In the MOF question [1] it was asked if $G$ is a second-countable profinite group with uncountably many subgroups, does it follow that it has uncountably many closed subgroups modulo conjugacy?

A counter-example of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ was provided leading to a negative answer to the above. This then leads to the following question:

Is there a classification of those profinite groups $G$ which have uncountably many subgroups but countably many subgroups modulo conjugacy?

Note that there is a full classification of those profinite groups which have a countable number of subgroups [2,3].

[1] [Spaces of closed subgroups of a profinite group up to conjugacy](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373271/spaces-of-closed-subgroups-of-a-profinite-group-up-to-conjugacy)

[2] D. L. Boyer, *Enumeration theorems in infinite abelian groups*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **7** (1956) 565-570, DOI: [10.2307/2033351](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2033351).

[3] P. Gartside and M. Smith, *Counting the closed subgroups of profinite groups*, J. Group Theory. **13** (2010) 41-61, DOI: [10.1515/JGT.2009.029](https://doi.org/10.1515/JGT.2009.029)